# Stats probability help!

Tags: probability, statistics

A manufacturer of light bulbs claims that its light bulbs have a mean life of 704 hours and a standard deviation of 116 hours. You purchased 143 of these bulbs and decided that you would purchase more if the mean life of your current sample exceeded 680 hours. What is the probability that you will not buy again from this manufacturer? (Round your answer to four decimal places.) 
What equation do I use?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to calculate here is the Standard Error of the Mean (SEM), which is given by:

$$\sigma_M = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt N}$$

where $\sigma$ is the population standard deviation and $N$ is the sample size.

The probability that the mean of a given sample of size $N$ will lie above $\displaystyle \mu - z\sigma_M$ is  can be computed by looking up a table of $z$-scores or using a calculator.

In this case, $\displaystyle \sigma_M = \frac{116}{\sqrt{143}} = 9.7004$.

The $z$-score you're interested in is given by $\displaystyle \frac{\mu_s - \mu_p}{\sigma_M} = \frac{680 - 704}{9.7004} = -2.4741$. Here, $\mu_s$ and $\mu_p$ represent the sample and population means, respectively.

The probability that your sample mean will lie *below* a $z$-score of $-2.4741$ is $0.00668$.

Hence the probability that your sample mean will lie above that is $1 - 0.00668 = 0.9933$.

Answer (score 0):

$P(\bar{X}>680)=P\left( \frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}>\frac{680-704}{\frac{116}{\sqrt{143}}} \right)=P(Z>-2.47)=1-0.006756=.99324$. Remember that if we want the probability of being greater than a certain value we can take 1 and subtract the probability of being less than that same value.